# How can this Javascript code handle the if/else statements better, or possibly use switches?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, submit

First off, if this is against the rules, or frowned upon I'm very sorry and feel free to downvote/close. I'm desperately stuck.

I'm having trouble with an HTML page I wrote which is supposed to consist of inputs with certain requirements, adding div's to display error messages , and automatically update those error messages onblur. The assignment was made to test our javascript skills, and thus must be completely validated through javascript.

Here are a few of the guidelines...

validating the form for four separate things:

- presence of required fields
- equality of password fields
- conformance to a password policy (one uppercase, one number, length > 7)
- validity of the email address

When any one of these are violated, I should deactivate the form’s submit button so that it is not clickable and add a child "div" to the error-display containing an error message describing the situation.

The code seems correct to me, and works spontaneously, but i believe since javascript is looked at one line at a time it isn't displaying error messages correctly or even getting to certain parts of my code at all.

Here is my large chunk of javascript code, I am mainly looking for a way to break out of these if/else blocks that my code seems stuck in:

```js
function formValidation() {

  var form = document.getElementById('project-form');
  var username = document.getElementById('username');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone-number');
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var password = document.getElementById('password');
  var passwordConfirmation = document.getElementById('password-confirmation');
  var submit = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
  var errorDisplay = document.getElementById('error-display');
  var missingFieldBoolean = false;
  var passwordMismatchBoolean = false;
  var isUpper = false;
  var isNumber = false;
  var passwordLength = false;
  var validEmail = false;
  var createDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  var passwordConstraint, passwordConstraintError;
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

  //Checks all fields for empty values and updates error div

  if (username.value.length == 0 || name.value.length == 0 || email.value.length == 0 || password.value.length == 0 || passwordConfirmation.value.length == 0) {

    missingField = errorDisplay.appendChild(createDiv);

    missingField.setAttribute("id", "required-field-error");

    missingFieldError = document.getElementById('required-field-error');

    missingFieldError.innerHTML = "Missing Fields: ";

    if (username.value.length == 0) {
      missingFieldError.innerHTML += "Username - ";
    }
    if (name.value.length == 0) {
      missingFieldError.innerHTML += "Full Name - ";
    }
    if (email.value.length == 0) {
      missingFieldError.innerHTML += "Email - ";
    }
    if (password.value.length == 0) {
      missingFieldError.innerHTML += "Password - ";
    }
    if (passwordConfirmation.value.length == 0) {
      missingFieldError.innerHTML += "Password Confirmation - ";
    }
  } else {
    errorDisplay.removeChild(missingFieldError);
    missingFieldBoolean = true;
  }

  //Checks password vs password confirmation to see if they match, else updates error div

  if (password.value != passwordConfirmation.value) {
    passwordMismatch = errorDisplay.appendChild(createDiv);

    passwordMismatch.setAttribute("id", "password-mismatch-error");

    passwordMismatchError = document.getElementById('password-mismatch-error');

    passwordMismatchError.innerHTML = "The Password and Password Confirmation do not match. Please re-enter.";
  } else {
    errorDisplay.removeChild(passwordMismatchError);
    passwordMismatchBoolean = true;
  }

  //for loop to iterate through password to check for required characters, else updates error div

  for (var index = 0; index < password.value.length; index++) {
    if (password.value.charAt(index) == password.value.charAt(index).toUpperCase) {
      isUpper = true;
    }
    if ("0123456789".indexOf(password.value.charAt(index)) > -1) {
      isNumber = true;
    }
    if (password.value.length > 7) {
      passwordLength = true;
    } else {
      passwordConstraint = errorDisplay.appendChild(createDiv);

      passwordConstraint.setAttribute("id", "password-constraint-error");

      passwordConstraintError = document.getElementById('password-constraint-error');

      passwordConstraintError.innerHTML = "The Password must be 8 characters long, with one uppercase letter and one number. ";
    }
  }

  //checks if password constraints are met and removes div if true

  if (isUpper && isNumber && passwordLength) {
    errorDisplay.removeChild(passwordConstraintError);
  }

  //checks email, if invalid it adds error div, else it removes the div   ***NOT WORKING***

  if (!(mailformat.test(email.value))) {
    invalidEmail = errorDisplay.appendChild(createDiv);

    invalidEmail.setAttribute("id", "invalid-email-error");

    invalidEmailError = document.getElementById('invalid-email-error');

    invalidEmailError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
  } else {
    errorDisplay.removeChild(invalidEmailError);
    validEmail = true;
  }

  //if all requirements are met and true, submit button becomes enabled  ***NOT WORKING***

  if (isUpper && isNumber && passwordLength && missingFieldBoolean && passwordMismatchBoolean && validEmail) {

    submit.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="error-display"></div>

<br>
<form id="project-form" action="/submit.php" method="get" onclick="formValidation()">

  <label>Username:</label>

  <input id="username" type="text" onblur="formValidation()" required>
  <c>*</c>

  <br>
  <label>Full Name:</label>

  <input id="name" type="text" onblur="formValidation()" required>
  <c>*</c>

  <br>
  <label>Phone Number:</label>

  <input id="phone-number" type="tel">

  <br>
  <label>Email:</label>

  <input id="email" type="email" onblur="formValidation()" required>
  <c>*</c>

  <br>
  <label>Password:</label>

  <input id="password" type="password" required onblur="formValidation()">
  <c>*</c>

  <br>
  <label>Confirm Password:</label>

  <input id="password-confirmation" type="password" required onblur="formValidation()">
  <c>*</c>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot in advance, and again sorry if i'm breaking the rules.

Comment: You have a lot of undeclared variables to start with, unless they're declared globally and you didn't include them here. It's causing a lot of errors. Do you know how to use the debugger in your browser?

Comment: Yes, at least fairly well.  I saw that it was breaking on many of the else blocks, when i try to remove child divs.  I noticed i didn't declare some of the variables in connection with removing and adding the error divs. I'll declare them where the rest of the variables are declared.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the inputs into an object instead, that way you could automatically iterate over the object.

```
const fieldValues = [
  'username',
  'name',
  'phone-number',
  'email',
  'password',
  'password-confirmation',
]
.reduce((fieldsSoFar, fieldName) => {
  fieldsSoFar[fieldName] = document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
  return fieldsSoFar;
}, {});

const missingFieldsStr =
  Object.entries(fieldValues)
  .filter(([, fieldValue]) => fieldValue.length === 0)
  .map(([fieldName]) => {
    const words = fieldName.split(' ');
    const upperWords = words.map(word => word.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    return upperWords;
  })
  .join(', ');
if (missingFieldsStr) {
  // display it
}

// skipping some lines...

const hasUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(fieldValues.password);
const hasNumber = /[0-9]/.test(fieldValues.password);
```

And so on.

Don't implicitly create global variables - strongly consider using a linter.

Only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately using or inserting HTML markup (which can have security and encoding problems). When you're setting or retrieving text values, use `textContent` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll have to do some research on that as i've not learned that deeply into HTML/javascript. I appreciate it, and hope it'll help me!